# Problems with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

someone can help me with procedure?

[image]

i get error:

[image]

Where is problem?

Comment: post text code  and not image (only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a procedure with more than one statement in the body, you need to use `BEGIN...END`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addItemToRepository(IN name VARCHAR(50), IN rfid VARCHAR(20),
  IN type VARCHAR(20), IN manufacturer INT, IN model VARCHAR(30), IN toRent TINYINT)
NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  SET @typeid = (SELECT id FROM dictionary WHERE value = type LIMIT 1);

  INSERT INTO depository (name, rfidtag, type, manufacturer, model, torent)
  VALUES (name, rfid, @typeid, manufacturer, model, torent);
END
```

Note I changed `select(@typeid)` in your insert statement. It's unnecessary to use select, and you can't do it without putting it inside a subquery in parentheses anyway.

I have some more comments:

- Make sure your IN parameter names are distinct from your column names, or else you might create ambiguous SQL statements, that is MySQL doesn't know if you mean `manufacturer` the in parameter or `manufacturer` the column in the depository table. It's not an error, but it might insert a NULL because it's using `manufacturer` from the non-existing row. So I suggest the habit of naming in parameters with a prefix like "p" indicating parameter.
- Declare a local variable instead of using session variables. MySQL treats them differently.
- Consider using the alternative `INSERT...SET` syntax.

Here's my suggestion:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addItemToRepository(IN pName VARCHAR(50), IN pRfid VARCHAR(20),
  IN pType VARCHAR(20), IN pManufacturer INT, IN pModel VARCHAR(30), IN pToRent TINYINT)
NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  DECLARE vTypeid INT;

  SELECT id INTO vTypeid FROM dictionary WHERE value = pType LIMIT 1;

  INSERT INTO depository
  SET name         = pName, 
      rfidtag      = pRfid, 
      type         = vTypeid, 
      manufacturer = pManufacturer, 
      model        = pModel, 
      toRent       = pToRent;
END
```

Comment: you are the best. Thanks you for answer :) Your suggestions are very valuable to me.